# The minimal $C^1$ hypersurface

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $S_0\subset \mathbb R^N$ be given, where we assume that $S_0$ is a **connected** $C^1$ hyper surface and $\mathcal H^{N-1}(S_0)<\infty$. Here $S_0$ may not be able to represented as a graph. (up to rotation)

Now assume in some way I remove some points from $S_0$ and have a new set $S$, the new set $S$, which is embedded in $S_0$, can be represented as a graph and also every point in $S$ has density 1. (Now $S$ may not be connected)

My question: can I find a new **connected** $C^1$ hyper surface $S^\ast$ such that $S^\ast$ contains $S$ and can be represented as a graph? If yes, I can transfer $S^\ast$ into a hyperplane, so does $S$ itself.

My goal is to find a way to flatten $S$...i.e., transfer it into a hyperplane.

---

My try: Let the collection $\mathcal S:=\{S_n\}$ be connected $C^1$ hyper surface and contains $S$, i.e., $S\subset S_n$ for each $n$. Then I know the collection $\mathcal S$ is not empty since at least $S_0$ is inside. Then I can have a ascending chain $S_i$ such that
$$
S\subset\cdots\subset S_n\subset S_{n-1}\subset\cdots\subset S_1
$$
and hence $\bar S:=\bigcap S_n$ is the upper bound for this chain and hence by [Zorn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma) we have there exists at least one maximal element, we call it $C^\ast$.

In the comment, I realize that $\bar S$ may not be $C^1$. Then what regularity condition should I add?

I think $C^*$ is the surface I want. **But I have trouble to prove it is actually can be represented as a graph.** If I can, then by local chart and usual trick we also do when we study Sobolev space, I could flatten $C^\ast$, i.e., flatten $S$ as I wanted.

Any help is really welcome!

Comment: I believe you forgot some hypotheses on $S$. Otherwise the first sentence is wrong by taking, among many others, $S=\mathbb R^N$.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi $S$ belongs to $S_0$ which is a finite hyper surface

Comment: This is **not** what you said: "Let a set $S\subset \mathbb R ^N$ be given. *We know that there exits* a $C^1$ hyper surface [...]".

Comment: I don't understand at all why you are doing such an argument. Why would $C^*$ be a better candidate for being a graph? The intersection of $C^1$ hypersurfaces is not an hypersurface, with no additional hypotheses. 
This is not even an issue, since no $S_n$ exists, a priori, without assumptions on $S$.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi I updated my question, please have a look. The existence of $S_n$ is because I know $S\subset S_0$ where $S_0$ is a $C^1$ hyper surface.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi also, could you tell me in what hypotheses that the intersection of $C^1$ hyper surfaces is still a $C^1$ hyper surfaces? Will they be a Lipschitz hyper surfaces in the end?

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi: I think I found another way to bypass my problem. Thanks for your comment! But I am still very confused why the intersection of $C^1$ hyper surfaces, especially for the chain, is not $C^1$? Any example?

Comment: Btw, I think it should be fine if they all contain each other.